# How can I echo to /dev/tty?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, cygwin, tty

Is there a way to send something like an "end of data" after executing

`echo "test" > /dev/tty1`

in order to gain the "input cursor" back to "receiving" terminal (in this case tty1)?

Screenshot: http://picload.org/image/acdwigg/tty.png

Comment: Not sure, what you meant by `in order to gain the "input cursor" back to "receiving" terminal (in this case tty1)?` (The screenshot link is not working from here..)

Comment: After a command is executed, $PS1 is prompt. something like $: or user@server. if i echo something to a terminal window, in this case tty1, i have to push "enter" in the terminal window (tty1).

Comment: Please write a clear question, Some user (including me) cannot understand it correctly

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Shell scripting is programming and shell utilities and behavior are on topic to a point here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `echo > /dev/tty` you can't achieve that. But you can do that by sending a signal to process which are using that tty.

For example:

```
kill -s SIGINT `ps -ft pts/2 | grep pts/2 | cut -d ' ' -f 5`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo "test" > /dev/tty
test
```

```
Cygwin supports the following character devices commonly found on POSIX systems:

/dev/tty    The current controlling tty of a session.
```

[`Special filenames`](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html)

Answer (score 2):

centos will print out your string in the console you select

```
#run on pts/8
[root@C203-ATC ONT]# uname -a
Linux C203-ATC 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 04:27:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@C203-ATC ONT]# echo "test" > /dev/pts/3
[root@C203-ATC ONT]# 

[root@C203-ATC BASIC]# tty
/dev/pts/3
#checked on pts/3  
[root@C203-ATC BASIC]# test
(cursor)
#cursor pending ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it like that.
The '>' redirection operator makes it so that for the WHOLE execution time standard input IS the `echo` command, and you can't just change it later.

You might want to rethink your needs and implementation.